# How do I load a JSON asset into my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

```
String data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/data.json");
final jsonResult = json.decode(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

What problem are you having?

You can try this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

String data = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/data.json");
final jsonResult = json.decode(data);
```